# With recursive over a complex hierarchy

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

I'm trying to use with recursive for a pretty complex hierarchy that looks like this:

```
Root    
|    
Second   
|   
Third   
|   
Leaf
```

But can also be like this(without the second):

```
Root       
|   
Third   
|   
Leaf
```

My SQL query looks like this:

```
with recursive relations as 
(select parent_id, child_id, 1 as h_level, array[parent_id,child_id] as fullpath
 from public.entity_relations where parent_type = 4
union all 
 select c.parent_id, c.child_id, p.h_level+1, p.fullpath || c.child_id 
 from public.entity_relations c join relations p on p.child_id = c.parent_id)
select * from relations;
```

Here is a sqlfiddle link with the relations table and with recursive query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/31793/1/0

The problem is that the recursion returns the sub-paths of this hierarchy.
I am interested only in the fullest paths of each hierarchy, in this example only these records:

```
BB  CC  2   A,BB,CC
C   D   3   A,B,C,D
```

Note: I know that the "sub paths" are necessary for the recursion,
so I am looking for a way to filter out the redundant records after the recursion.

Comment: What result set do you want returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select only leaves (nodes without children) in the final query:

```
with recursive relations as (
    select 
        parent_id, 
        child_id, 
        1 as h_level, 
        array[parent_id,child_id] as fullpath
    from entity_relations where parent_type = 4
union all 
    select 
        c.parent_id, 
        c.child_id, 
        p.h_level+1, 
        p.fullpath || c.child_id 
    from entity_relations c 
    join relations p on p.child_id = c.parent_id
)
select *
from relations r
where not exists (
    select from entity_relations e
    where e.parent_id = r.child_id
)

 parent_id | child_id | h_level | fullpath
-----------+----------+---------+-----------
 C         | D        |       2 | {A,C,D}
 BB        | CC       |       2 | {A,BB,CC}
 C         | D        |       3 | {A,B,C,D}
(3 rows)
```

It turns out that there are two paths that lead to the leaf `D`. You can choose one of them depending on the level.

```
...
select distinct on (child_id) *
from relations r
where not exists (
    select from entity_relations e
    where e.parent_id = r.child_id
)
order by child_id, h_level desc

 parent_id | child_id | h_level | fullpath
-----------+----------+---------+-----------
 BB        | CC       |       2 | {A,BB,CC}
 C         | D        |       3 | {A,B,C,D}
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
with recursive relations as (
      select parent_id, child_id, 1 as h_level, array[parent_id,child_id] as fullpath
      from public.entity_relations
      where parent_type = 4
      union all 
      select c.parent_id, c.child_id, p.h_level+1, p.fullpath || c.child_id 
      from public.entity_relations c join
           relations p
           on p.child_id = c.parent_id
     )
select r.*
from relations r
where not exists (select 1
                  from relations r2
                  where r2.fullpath @> r.fullpath and
                        r2.fullpath <> r.fullpath
                 );
```